# Need PC Text editor/ IDE with the following features:

Tags: ide

I'm needing what seems like common sense tools for one source:
1) Sytax highlighting. (Specifically for PHP)
2) Integrated Terminal (Don't need to open Putty for ssh, it's integrated into IDE)
3) Search function that can search local directories. (Can select any directory on local machine and do searches on text content)

This is all available in Coda but I haven't found a single PC tool that does this well.
Aptana comes close, but has no search function for local directories. (Seriously? How do I find functions that aren't part of a project then?)

Any help in finding this elusive wonder would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ should do for 1) and 3)
2) possuldibly could be achieved with plugin NppFTP

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/

Comment: NppFTP doesn't do recursive deletes, which is infuriating.